# Possible values RFC_NAME field in S_RFC object

Tags: saprfc, sap-basis

Where can I find the possible values for RFC_NAME field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC_NAME is the function group. For a given RFC function, the function group is given in the "Property" tab in se37.

You can also use the '*' value for unchecked access. This can be useful during initial development, but should not be used otherwise (RFC function should be constrained on what they can do...)

Regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

More context is needed. My guess is that you need the function group. Look at the function in se37.Click on the "display object list" icon. On the left you will see the name of the "function group" this is probably what you are looking for.